# How to resolve unexpected token error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using bellow babelrc setting.

```
{
"presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}
```

then, I when I use **...reducers** I get unexpected token error.
Do you know how to resolve it?
I expected that cause is reducer setting.
And If I add 'stage-1' on babelrc. it can resolve.
But I don't want to add it. Please tell me it except for adding 'stage-1' on babelrc.

Thanks!

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { syncHistoryWithStore, routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import * as storage from './persistence/storage';
import randomToken from './utlis/random';
import getPastDays from './utlis/pastFutureDays';
import * as reducers from './reducers';
import {
  App,
  Home,
} from './components';
import style from './css/style.css';

const reducer = combineReducers({
  ...reducers,
  routing: routerReducer,
});
```

**./reducers/application.js**

```
import { REGISTER_TOKEN } from '../constants';

const initialState = {
  token: null,
  createdAt: null,
};

export default function access(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === REGISTER_TOKEN) {
    return { token: state.token };
  }
  return state;
}
```

**./reducers/index.js**

```
export { default as cityForecast } from './cityForecast';
export { default as application } from './application';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object spread operator proposed for the next versions of JavaScript which lets you use the spread (...) operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to another in a more succinct way.

Unfortunately ES6 spread operator works only with arrays.

If you dont want to add babel preset for that, you can use `Object.assign` instead.

So you can combine your reducers in the following way:

```
const reducer = combineReducers(
    Object.assign(reducers, {routing: routerReducer})
);
```

You can find more info here https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/

Comment: Uhmm, I try to write like this.

Comment: `const reducerData = Object.assign({}, reducers);

 const reducer = combineReducers({
   reducerData,
   routing: routerReducer,
 });`

But I still can't resolve it.
Do I make mistake how to write?